# Squashing Promise<Observable<HttpEvent<any>>> to Observable<HttpEvent<any>>

Tags: angular, rxjs, es6-promise

A given Angular HTTP Interceptor must implement

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>
```

The returned `Observable<HttpEvent<any>>` usually is the product of `next.handle(req)` (after - perhaps - modifying the request somehow).

In my case, I need to set some headers, but to find which headers, internally I need to invoke some methods that return `Promises`. Like this:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  const req1: Promise<HttpRequest<unknown>> = this.service.getFutureValue().then(value => {
    const headers = req.headers.append('X-Custom-Header', value);
    return req.clone({headers});
  });
  ...
}
```

I need to chain `next` using `req1`:

```
const x = req1.then(r => next.handle(r));
```

Now I have a `Promise<Observable<HttpEvent<any>>>`, but I need to somehow transform it to `Observable<HttpEvent<any>>`.

Conceptually I think this is somehow valid, given that both `Promises` and `Observables` are future values.

I'm pretty sure this is a simple transformation, but I don't see how.

**EDIT**

This may work: `from(x).pipe(mergeAll())`. But I'll keep looking for something more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following:

```typescript
return from(this.service.getFutureValue())
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(x => {
      const headers = req.headers.append('X-Custom-Header', x);
      return next.handle(req.clone({ headers }));
    })
  )
```

Or optionally:

```typescript
return from(this.service.getFutureValue())
  .pipe(
    map(x => {
      const headers = req.headers.append('X-Custom-Header', x);
      return req.clone({ headers });
    }),
    mergeMap(next.handle)
  )
```

Comment: Not very readable.... But better than my solution anyway. Your second option.... Maybe it will not work because `next.handle` may not be bound to `next`.